# what does ::operator() do?

Tags: c++, operator-keyword

```
    struct reserved_memory
    {
     void *safety;
     size_t safety_size;
     reserved_memory(size_t size) : safety_size(size)
     {
       init();
     }

     bool use() {
        if (safety) {
            ::operator(safety); 
            safety=0;
            return true;
        } else
            return false;
     }
    private:
     void init() 
     {
        safety=::operator new(safety_size);
     }
   }
```

I have this code that isn't compiling - and I also have never seen this before. Is this calling the constructor? There is no overloaded () operator in the struct...

Comment: To the best of my knowledge `::operator(safety)` isn't legal C++ code.  Perhaps there's some ridiculous edge case I'm not aware of, though.

Comment: The real question is.... if you don't know what this code does (which is nothing, evidently), why did you write it?!

Comment: I didn't write it, and would like to know about it more, however its not compiling so I can't debug through it =[

Comment: `I have this code that isn't compiling - and I also have never seen this before.` Maybe it never worked, and thats why you have never seen it before.

Comment: @EnabrenTane: (a) Your nick is a nice twist on the original name. Good job. (b) I love you.

Comment: @templatetypedef: The ridiculous part of the language is that there is perhaps some edge case you're not aware of.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Seems pretty obvious that whoever wrote that code intended to call `::operator delete(safety)`

(evidence: `safety` is a pointer; it was initialised with `::operator new(safety_size)`, and after they erroneously call `::operator(safety)` they reset it to zero).

<strike>As for the purpose of the code as a whole, I have no idea -- looks like it's probably part of a pretty poor design.</strike>

Ken Bloom has provided a plausible answer for the purpose of the code: reserving some emergency memory to be released in dire circumstances (to give enough breathing room to be able to emit an error message). See [his answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4687166/what-does-operator-do/4687315#4687315) for more details.

Comment: +1 I hereby delete all of my answers to this question. (No wonder I didn't pick up on that. He hadn't added the constructor when I answered.)

Comment: @Ken: Ah, the benefits of being late to the party ;)

Comment: On old, old Macs (and maybe still on some low-memory handheld systems), you used to reserve some memory as a safety so that you could free it up when you ran out of memory, and so that you could use it to alert the user that something was amiss and save all their work. I saw the technique in *Programming Starter Kit for Macintosh* by Jim Trudeau.

Comment: @Ken: Interesting! Maybe you should put that back in as an answer?

Comment: yep this is right. i made a mistake w a script and it auto deleted the delete keyword. my mistake

Answer (score 5):

A note about what this code appears to be doing:

On old Macs (before MacOS X, and maybe still on some low-memory handheld systems), you used to reserve some memory as a safety so that you could free it up when you ran out of memory, and so that you could use it to alert the user that something was amiss and save all their work. I saw the technique in Programming Starter Kit for Macintosh by Jim Trudeau.

So this appears to be the same kind of thing -- reserving a block of memory by size, and freeing it up when it's needed. Apparently the programmer didn't want to go with the more usual idiom of `safety=new char[safety_size]` and `delete[] safety`.

Answer (score 1):

You're trying to call a free function `operator()` on a `void*`. To the best of my knowledge, this does not exist. Hence, it does not compile for you.

I would offer alternative suggestions if I had any idea whatsoever about what you're attempting to accomplish here.

Comment: In fact, you're not trying to call `operator()`. You're trying to call `operator`, which most certainly does *not* exist in your testcase.

Comment: Apparently, everybody who did not divine that there was a missing `delete` or that the mysterious call to `::operator()` had to do with memory allocation was downvoted.  *shrug*  Kinda dumb if you ask me.

Comment: It's wrong, regardless of whether it meets the intent of his question. It misses several subtleties of C++ syntax. #1 `operator` is a reserved word. #2 to call the `()` operator, using this syntax, you'd need `operator()(safety)`, and #3 you'd be calling a global `()` operator, and no such operator can exist. The other downvoted answer is also wrong for reason #2.

Comment: @Ken: Pretty sure I covered at least #2 and #3. I don't see how possibly omitting #1 (though I don't see its relevance) makes the answer "wrong".

Comment: When I read your answer, there was a 50/50 thing going on in my head as to whether you were saying you could call a function named `operator` (noting that it's a common convention when discussing C or C++ to refer to functions like `foo()` with the empty parenthese to indicate a function -- meaning you ran afoul of problem #1) or whether  `::operator(safety)` should be a syntactically valid way to call the `()` operator (meaning you ran afoul of problem #2), and that the only problem is that it's not defined. Note also, that the fact that it isn't defined only gets you part way to #3.

Comment: @Ken: I think I covered the fact that his code won't work, no matter which of your three issues I focused on. Downvoting is for incorrect answers. Upvoting is for answers that you think are in-depth. If you feel that I was not in-depth enough then don't upvote me, but down-voting me is unsolicited.

Comment: @Tomalak: People need to know more than simply the fact that their code doesn't work. He already knew his code didn't work -- he wanted to know why!

Comment: @KenBloom: I told him why. `operator()` on a `void*` does not exist.

Comment: (And nor can a free function named `operator` that takes a `void*`, which is the real problem.)

Answer (score 1):

Though obviously the `::operator delete()` answer is correct, people here are still missing syntactic subtleties about the `()` operator.

1. This cannot be calling a method named `operator`, because `operator` is a reserved word.
2. If the code is trying to call an overloaded parentheses operator, it should  say `operator()(safety)` -- the first `()` telling you it's the parentheses operator, and the second passing a parameter.
3. Even if you were to fix that, `::operator()(safety)` (defined at the global scope) cannot exist, becuase (and I'll quote G++ here, because it says it better than I could) `’operator()()’ must be a nonstatic member function`.

Answer (score 0):

What you have is not legal C++.  It calls the function call operator as a free function declared at global scope.  It's not legal to declare the function call operator as a free function at all at any scope.  It must be declared as a non-static member function.

If it were legal, it would be calling a function that looked like this:

```
void operator ()(void *foo)
{
   ::std::cout << "operator()(void *)\n";
}
```

But if you put such code into a compiler the compiler will tell you it's not legal.