# what does `::operator new` do?

Tags: c++, overloading, new-operator

I am looking through some example code of overloading new/delete

and there I have the following

```
// manage memory for instances
void * roun_class:: operator new(std::size_t s)
{
    void * result(::operator new(s));
    return result;    
}
```

This is the first time , I am looking at **::operator**. And I cannot find anything about it in Google/SO. So , can someone please explain why we have :: and no class infront of it. What is so special about this **::operator** ?? ,

FYI, I have already looked at the following
[what does ::operator() do?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4687166/what-does-operator-do)
Does not really answer my question though

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A leading `::` generally indicates the global namespace (ie, no namespace), so I'm guessing `::operator new` is necessary to indicate that we're talking about the built-in new, and not recursively calling the class's `new`.

Answer (score 5):

`::operator new(std::size_t)` is the `new(std::size_t)` operator in the global namespace (ie: one of the default memory allocation functions).

It's called `::operator new` here because if it weren't, this `operator new` would simply be calling itself over again, which would lead to a stack overflow.

Comment: But using `::operator new` lead to stackoverflow anyway... hurrr

Comment: Heh heh...  "A" stack overflow, not *the* Stack Overflow.  :)

Answer (score 3):

**::** is called the scope resolution operator.
Hope this example helps:

```
int count = 0;

int main(void) {
  int count = 0;
  ::count = 1;  // set global count to 1
  count = 2;    // set local count to 2
  return 0;
}
```

See C++ reference : http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/macxhelp/v6v81/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.ibm.vacpp6m.doc%2Flanguage%2Fref%2Fclrc05cplr175.htm

And as far as the overloading of new is concerned. This is what I got for you.

```
void* operator new  ( std::size_t count );  //(1)   
void* operator new[]( std::size_t count ); //(2)    
void* operator new  ( std::size_t count, const std::nothrow_t& );  //(3)    
void* operator new[]( std::size_t count, const std::nothrow_t& );  //(4)    
void* operator new  ( std::size_t, void* ptr );  //(5)  
void* operator new[]( std::size_t, void* ptr );  //(6)
```

**The allocation function can be replaced/overloaded in two ways:** 
**in the global scope:**

> in order to call it, the signature of the overloaded
>   allocation functions must be visible at the place of allocation,
>   except for implicitly declared default allocation functions. This
>   allocation function will be used for all allocations with
>   corresponding parameters in the current program

**in the local scope:**

> the overloaded operator new must be static public member function of
>   the class. This allocation function will be used only for allocations
>   of that particular class.

Seource : http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/new/operator_new

Answer (score 1):

it calls the new operator in the "global" namespace.  This is the one built into the C++ compiler.